# HTML5 Canvas: Filling all enclosed spaces in a random drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fill

In my scenario, I am using lineTo() to draw various random figures on a HTML5 canvas. I need to fill all enclosed area with some fill color, but when I call fill() it just doesn't do what I want: Some areas are filled, but others are left white.

I understand that what I want could probably be achieved by drawing some of the lines from B to A instead of from A to B, but since the shapes are random, I am afraid that isn't possible. :) Any alternatives?

Comment: could you post an imageyour current result (or a link to it if your rep doesn't allow) ?

Comment: If your lineTo's cross, you might define which fill rule to apply, eg: `context.fill('evenodd')` or `context.fill('nonzero')`

Comment: I am afraid my rep doesn't allow uploads, and I currently don't have access to an upload service. Basically, the issue looks similar to the one described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ...only that I am getting results like the star at the very bottom (not all shapes filled) with the default nonzero algo. Applying 'evenodd' will not fill any more enclosed areas, but instead all lines will disappear (the outer ones as well).